# TextView inflater and Fragmen vis code

Tags: android

The listed code workd just fine, but I want some more.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
     ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "HelpDetailsFragment.onCreateView() getCurrentIndex(): "+getCurrentIndex());

    Log.i(TAG, "HelpDetailsFragment.onCreateView() container.getChildCount() first log: "+container.getChildCount());

    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());

    TextView headerText = (TextView) new TextView(getActivity());   

    // headerText.inflate(getActivity(), R.id.textView1, null);

    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
               TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getActivity()
               .getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    headerText.setHeight(height);
    headerText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24);
    headerText.setText(HelpScreenData.HELP_HEADERS[getCurrentIndex()]);     

    frameLayout.addView(headerText);

    return  frameLayout;
```

}

I try to customize the text appearance some more with values from an XML file via the commented out line.
But that will not work, can / will someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, dont create your layouts like that! I highly recommend you to use XML based layouts. Then in your `onCreateView()` method inflate your XML layout and return it.

Example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
     ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null); //my_layout is your layout defined in XML  

    TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    Button button = v.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    //do whatever with your textView, set OnClickListener to button etc...        


    return  v; //return inflated layout 
}
```

I would suggest you to read some basic tutorials about layouts at [Android Dev website](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the respons, but this suggestion leaves me with: "AndroidRuntime(615): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"
This is a message I've had meny times over and I don't know to get around it.

Comment: change the line inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null); with inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);